# Assigned image height is diffrent then original height

Tags: javascript

I need assign image height and width to variable, but variable have other value then image size.

My code:

```
var image = document.getElementById('imgUploadedImage');
var maxSize = image.width > image.height ? image.width : image.height;
var minSize = image.width > image.height ? (image.width/image.height)*295 : 236;
```

What I get in firebug:

```
maxSize     93

minSize     1714.6875

image.height        749

image.width     1200

image.width > image.height ? image.width : image.height     1200

(image.clientWidth/image.clientHeight)*295      472.63017356475297

(image.clientWidth/image.clientHeight)      1.6021361815754338
```

Why maxSize is 93 instead 1200?
When I use clientHeight and clientWidht I get 0.

Comment: I tried your code, and 1200 is coming in maxSize. You must have reassigned some value to this variable. Try putting an alert for maxSize after 2nd line of above code.

Comment: Is the same.. max value is all time different

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. Result is kind of strange. However following changes made the code work as expected.

```
var image = document.getElementById('imgUploadedImage');
maxSize = image.width > image.height ? image.width : image.height;
minSize = image.width > image.height ? (image.width/image.height)*295 : 236; 
alert('max-size:'+maxSize+' min-size:'+minSize);
```

I don't know what was wrong with your code. May be a browser specific error.

Comment: Seems like grouping the evaluation part of the ternary operator also working. `(x>y) ? a():b()`